# Multiple Subprocesses Printing to File

Tags: python, subprocess

I currently have a problem when using two subprocesses (I will add more when I get this fixed) to print to a file. I'm getting the sum from awk and now I'm trying to print it to a file and it is not printing right. I'm using Python 2.6 and there is no way to upgrade. I am closing my files at the end of my program too, so that's not the problem.
edit:
The purpose of this code is to loop through files and count up the number of times a particular string comes up. Place them in files and then total the files in a final output file.

```
def serv2Process(HOST = "testServer.com"):
        encInTotal1 = 0
        signInTotal1 = 0
        p = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
            shell = False,
            stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
            close_fds = True)
        for line in p.stdout:
            if 'String to search'.lower() in line.lower():
                totalCount1 = totalCount1 +1
            if 'String 2 to search'.lower() in line.lower():
                totalCount2 = totalCount2 +1
        file1.write("%s\n" %totalCount1)
        file2.write("%s\n" %totalCount2)

        sys.stdout.flush()

    p1 =threading.Thread(target = serv1Process, args=(HOST1,), name = 'serv1Process')
    p2=threading.Thread(target = serv2Process, args= (HOST2,), name = 'serv2Process')
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    with open("SomeScriptName.%s" % strDateForm, 'w+')as search_file:
        search_file.write("Header: ")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}',"file1.%s" %strDateForm], shell=False, stdout=search_file,close_fds = True)
        proc.wait()

        search_file.write("\n")
        search_file.write("Header2: ")
        search_file.flush()
        proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '{s+=$1} END {print s}',"file2.%s" %strDateForm], shell=False, stdout=search_file,close_fds = True)
        proc2.wait()
    file1.close()
    file2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're not writing to the file the same time the started process is. To do so, make sure to flush the file before starting a process, and to wait for the process to finish before writing to it again.

```
with open("SomeFileName.%s" % strDateForm, 'w+') as search_file:

    search_file.write("header: ")
    search_file.flush()

    proc = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}',"AnotherFileName" ], shell=False, stdout=search_file,stderr = subprocess.PIPE,close_fds = True)
    proc.wait()

    search_file.write("Header 2: ")
    search_file.flush()

    proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '{s+=$1} END {print s}',"AThirdFileName"], shell=False, stdout=search_file,stderr = subprocess.PIPE,close_fds = True)
    proc2.wait()
```

Also you redirect `stderr` to a pipe, but you never read from it. If the subprocess produces enough output on stderr to fill the pipe buffer it will block. If you're not interested in stderr, either don't redirect it to let it go to the terminal or redirect it to `/dev/null`.

And you try to flush `sys.stdout`, but that won't really affect anything related to this code.

---

edit: after seeing your updated code, some remarks:

- assuming the open files `file1` and `file2` are the files the `awk` subprocesses try to read: make sure to flush or close them *before* starting any processes.
- you call `sys.stdout.flush()` multiple times, but there's no point in doing that. You're not really writing to sys.stdoutd, so flushing it doesn't really do anything. flush `file1`, `file2` and `search_file` instead!
- If this isn't code for exercising the use of the `subprocess` module, you should probably consider using python directly to sum up the numbers from the file instead of shelling out to awk.

Comment: This just printed the headers to the files, not the result of the processes.

Comment: Are you sure your awk program produces any output? Try to remove the `stderr` redirection as I suggested, maybe you're getting some errors from the awk process instead.

Comment: Yes. When I run this with one output it works perfectly fine. But as soon as I throw another subprocess in it doesn't work

Comment: weird - when I try this exact code (with appropriate files containing some numbers) I get what I would expect (header - output - header - output)

Comment: I can maybe post more of my code to see if its something from above. Im not sure why it would be but its worth a shot

Comment: I tried to use variables instead of awk originally, but I could never get them to work correctly

Comment: Using flush fixed it. Thank you